# how to get the digest string format result from rust ring Digest

Tags: rust, hash, ring

I am using rust ring(`ring = "0.16.20"`) to get a message digest, this is my code:

```
use ring::{digest, test};

fn main() {
    let actual = digest::digest(&digest::SHA512, b"hello, world");
    let result = format!("{:x}", actual);
}
```

but it give me tips that:

```
`Digest` doesn't implement `LowerHex` (required by {:x})
```

what should I do to get the digest string from the ring `Digest` result? I also tried to found a `to_string()` method but failed. I also tried this way:

```
fn main() {
    let actual = digest::digest(&digest::SHA512, b"hello, world");
    let s = match str::from_utf8(actual.as_ref()) {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(e) => panic!("Invalid UTF-8 sequence: {}", e),
    };

    println!("result: {}", s);
    //let result = format!("{:x}", actual);
}
```

still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

use data_encoding(`data-encoding = "2.3.2"`) lib to get the string result:

```
let actual = digest::digest(&digest::SHA512, b"hello, world");
let calc_digest_str = HEXLOWER.encode(actual.as_ref());
```

Comment: This answer do not **really** answers the question *how to get the digest result string from rust ring Digest?*, it just goes straight to the format. I think you should either edit the question or the answer...

Comment: I have edit the question and I did not know is it precisely explain the goal.@Netwave

Comment: well you are missing the part in where you want it as a lowercase hextring, because the original question just ask for a simple string.